# Create hierarchical anonymous type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Is there any way to create anonymous type that references instances of itself?

```
var root = new { Name = "Root", Parent = ??? };
var child = new { Name = "Child", Parent = root };
var childOfChild = new { Name = "Grand child", Parent = child };
```

For example, we can reference delegate from itself:

```
Action run = null;
run = () => run();
```

Another example, we can create generic Stack of anonymous types:

```
static Stack<T> CreateStack<T>(params T[] values)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();

    foreach (var value in values)
        stack.Add(value);

    return stack;
}
```

Can you think of any ways to reference anonymous type from itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed... that the C# compiler will simply refuses to infer the type recursively. Take this sample code for example:

(From @Eric: Correct; the type inference engine requires that all the "input" types of a lambda be known before the "output" type of the lambda is inferred)

```
public void Run()
{
  var k = Generator((str, parent) => new {
    Name = str,
    Parent = parent
  });
}

public Func<string, T, T> Generator<T>(Func<string, T, T> generator)
{
  return (str, obj) => generator(str, obj);
}
```

This snippet fails to compile with an error that the compiler cannot infer the `<T>` to use with `Generator<T>`... thus I think it's impossible.

Comment: I've created new class already and asked on SO to check if my original task was impossible or not.

Comment: Interesting idea with generator!

Comment: Correct; the type inference engine requires that all the "input" types of a lambda be known before the "output" type of the lambda is inferred.

Answer (score 9):

Anonymous types in C# are *immutable*. Therefore all of their field values must have been present *before* the creation of the object and will never change. And therefore it is impossible to have a directly circular referencing anonymous type in C#.

Anonymous types in VB are mutable; you could probably figure out some way to do it in VB.

There might be a way to make an anonymous type *indirectly* reference itself, by, say, containing a delegate that when invoked, returns the instance of the anonymous type. I don't see any way off the top of my head to easily do that, but I also don't see a proof that doing so is impossible. Give it some thought and see what you come up with!

I assume this question is for entertainment purposes only. If you want to make a circularly-referential object, please make a nominal type.

Comment: My structure is immutable. Root has null as parent, direct root children reference Root, etc.

Comment: I've renamed question for clarity